# WebApi project does not start in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I have a solution with one WebApi2 project, Winforms project and other library projects.

The solution has 2 startup projects: the WebApi and Winforms projects (both set to Start) and the WebApi2 should be the first to start.

I've also checked the WebApi project's properties and the Asp-Net debugger is activated.

I'm using VS2015 community and IIS Express. I've just installed Update 3.

Is there any other setting that I need to set or is the problem caused with the new update, because a couple of days everything was working fine.

Comment: Any infos in the output window? Only the web api project does not start or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not entering debug mode was because in the project properties `Build` tab for the `Debug` configuration, the checkbox `Optimize Code` was checked.

Unchecking it solved the problem.